# How to access object data posted by ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to access an object with form data sent to my controller.  However, when I try to access objects I get values of null or 0. I used two methods, the first by serializing and the second by storing names and values in one object. (the code below sends/posts serialized)

Here is my JS...

```
$("#createUser").click(function() {

        //store input values
        var inputs = $('#newUserForm :input');
        var input = $('#newUserForm :input').serializeArray();
        console.log(input);

        //if I want just the values in one object
        var values = {};
        $(inputs).each(function() {
            values[this.name] = $(this).val();
        });
        console.log(values);

        if(LiveValidation.massValidate( validObj )){
            $.post('./adminPanel/createUser', function(input){
                alert('Load was performed.');
                            //test confirmation box
                $("#msgbox").html("Grrrrreat");
                //drop down confirmation
                $("#msgbox").slideDown();
            });
        } else {
            //test fail box
            $("#failbox").html("Fail");
            $("#failbox").slideDown();
        }
    });
```

In the controller side I try to access data the following way...

```
$this->input->post("firstName")
```

where firstName is the name of the field.

Below is an image of the objects passed. 
Top being serialized array and the bottom a single object with all the names and values of form...

[image: objects created]

Comment: If you want the field `name`, you should query that field: `$this->input->post('name')` which would have `"firstName"` as value. I think your ajax call is just wrong. You want to send: `{"firstName": "jon"}`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can use jQuery's built in serialize/query string functions to get the data from a form: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

In your case:

```
var data = $('#newUserForm').serialize(); // is a string like "firstName=jon"
```

Comment: also noticed that passing data improperly.  The corrent way is $.post('./adminPanel/createUser', input, function(data){

Comment: Yup. And `input` is the `data` that I created in the example above with `Form.serialize()`. Your `data` is the server response.